# string vs text using Rails 3.2.* and Postgres - should I always just use text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I adopted a Rails app (Rails 3.2 and Postgres 9.4) that has a few Rails strings and we have gone past the 255 limit. This app had previously used MySQL rather than Postgres as backing store.  My understanding is that postgres handles strings and text the same. Is this correct? Are there any limitations that we should be aware of before migrating all our Rails strings to texts?

Issues of performance are a bit of a concern but not the dominant concern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html):

> **Tip**: There is no performance difference among these three types, apart from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type, and a few extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a length-constrained column. While `character(n)` has performance advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage in PostgreSQL; in fact `character(n)` is usually the slowest of the three because of its additional storage costs. In most situations `text` or `character varying` should be used instead.

The three types they're talking about are `char(n)`, `varchar(n)`, and `text`. The tip is essentially saying that:

- `char(n)` is the slowest due to blank padding and having to check the length constraint.
- `varchar(n)` is usually in the middle because the length constraint needs to be checked.
- `text` (AKA `varchar` with no `n`) is usually the fastest because there's no extra overhead.

Apart from the blank padding for `char(n)` and length checking for `char(n)` and `varchar(n)`, they're all handled the same behind the scenes.

With ActiveRecord, `t.string` is a `varchar` and `t.text` is `text`. If you don't have any hard length constraints on your strings then just use `t.text` with PostgreSQL.

Comment: but aren't `varchar` (with no length) and `text` the same thing in postgresql?

Comment: @sekmo AFAIK `t.string` used to be `varchar(255)` but is now `varchar` whereas `t.text` is and has always been `text`. So yes, at the PostgreSQL level, `text` and `varchar` (with no `n`) are the same (as noted in bullet point three) but `t.string` and `t.text` weren't always the same thing at the ActiveRecord level.