# What advantage to use varchar instead of text data type?

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

I am creating a table on PostgreSQL I know that the file is a char data type but despite I know that it will store maximum 100 chars I would like to know the next:

What are the advantages of a character or character varying instead of text?

**What I think I know**

If I am not wrong character is fixed length reserved in memory, and varchar is variable, the same as Text data type. This last is able to store at 1 GB of data but with a minimum of 0 kb, the same minimum as the varchar and char.

**Hypothetical case**

Then, guess that I am very lazy and despite I know that maximum I will store 100 chars I use text because it is able to store this 100chars and more if in the future is needed. What characteristics I am losing here to not use the appropriate data type?

Comment: Do you mean "instead", not "in front of"?

Comment: I expect fixed char columns to be fastest for reading.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Not necessarily: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31079819/479863. Not sure if that counts as a duplicate though.

Comment: @muistooshort: ah, I was thinking about mysql then. IIRC, that is true there.

Comment: There is not much we can add to the linked (excellent) answer, but some more context: `varchar` / `character varying` is ANSI-friendly, but not the form, which lack the length constraint. `text` is a usual extension to SQL, but not all vendors support it. Also, in PostgreSQL `text` is the default ("preferred") type of the string type category. See: `select * from pg_type where typcategory = 'S'`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: there is absolutely no difference whatsoever between  `varchar` or `text` in  terms of performance or storage requirements in Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: yes, we already established that I was wrong :)

Answer (score 9):

There is no significant difference between VARCHAR and TEXT:

[PostgreSQL: Difference between text and varchar (character varying)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848964/postgresql-difference-between-text-and-varchar-character-varying)